# Swift clear tableview data after pressing close button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to ask how do I clear the table view data after I press the close button? As what I understand in previous solution, is to use `removeall()` function before `tableview.reloadData()`. But, my `reloaddata` is at override main, because of that if I `removeall`, after I go in to my tableview all data will be lost already.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("popupname",name2_2)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        self.showAnimate()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
 name2_2.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()

        self.removeAnimate()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return name2_2.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedrow = [name2_2[indexPath.row]]
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMain1", sender: self)
        self.removeAnimate()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = name2_2[indexPath.row] as String

        return cell
    }

    func showAnimate()
    {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        });
    }

    func removeAnimate()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished)
            {
                self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to put in the function close, please guide me I really need help.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean by *"But, my reloaddata is at override main"*? To clear a table you update the data model so it has no data, then you reload the table view with `reloadData`. What's that issue you are having?

Comment: Thats the issues when I clear my data at override func viewdidload, the data is all gone after I go into it. What I want is clear the tableview data after I press the close button

Comment: Then clear the data model and call `reloadData` in your `close` method, not in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Erm thats the problem after I go into the viewcontroller I will also need to reload the table view data so I can see the list of data, so how should I do that? Is it I need to put in  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: [Edit] your question with relevant code for your table view data source methods. And update your code with your attempt to clear and reload the table view.

Comment: I just updated my code u can check

Comment: Thanks @RajeshkumarR solve it alrdy

Comment: Where's your current attempt to clear and reload the table view?

Comment: Hi @rmaddy i just updated my code can you help see what is the problem? I still cant clear the data after pressing the close button

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you verified that your close function is being called?

Comment: ya is called....

Comment: Hi @rmaddy is not working is it because after I run the popupviewcontroller the system automatically reload data, because of that the data cannot be clear?

Answer (score -2):

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return button.isSelected?0:name2_2.count
}；